# how to use the propertys of justifyContent when using flexDirection column

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, frontend, jsx

I want to use `justifyContent:'space-between'`with `flexDirection:'column'` 
This my code:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'space-between'}} >
              <CheckBox
              value={isSelected}
              onValueChange={setSelection}
              />
               <CheckBox
              value={isSelected2}
              onValueChange={setSelection2}
              />
               <CheckBox
              value={isSelected3}
              onValueChange={setSelection3}
              />
    </View>
```

I've tried many times to put space between them but it only work when i use `flexDirection:'row'`

Comment: When using column use alignItems

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing most important property.

```
display: 'flex'
```

In your example like

```
<View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'space-between'}} >
```

It should work like this as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your syntax is correct? The flex-column works with `justify-content: space-between` just fine.

https://codepen.io/treacych/pen/qBYBXdP